# Why my form glitch when I type someting to textfiled in java

Tags: java, netbeans, java-17

I use netbeans 18 and JDK 17.0.10 and when i run my form and using JTextField and this happen I already send my project for my friends and it work normal may be my netbeans have problem but I still need helpppppp

[here is my form when it glitch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFfHl.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Reviewing the following links might help you to improve the question: [The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Write a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), Show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also [The Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) may be able to help with any other questions using correctly this site. Add to the question the tag of the graphical framework you are using.

Comment: From the image you posted, it looks to me that you are using the [GUI builder](https://netbeans.apache.org/tutorial/main/kb/docs/java/quickstart-gui/) of NetBeans. If so, then [edit] your question and post the code that NetBeans generated so that I can try to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you Abra I think I know why my form glitch like that cause I use another language keyboard on windows and when I use US keyboard everything back to normal